# RTCMultiConnection scalable screenshare

Tags: rtcmulticonnection

I am working on a project to create a scalable screen sharing application using WebRTC. I started with RTCMultiConnection library, which seems excellent, and stumbled upon the following:

https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Video-Scalable-Broadcast.html
this example includes screensharing, but doesn't work at all.

https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Screen-Sharing.html
this one works, but not scalable

attempt to simply rework one code into another fails, seemingly scalable screenshare works in a completely different way from scalable video. Anyone was able to make it work?

Thanks for any directions at inputs!

P.S.: I am fine even if this works only in Chrome. I will pack this into Electron anyway so browser compatibility will never be a problem.

Comment: Also which version of server code do i need to use for this? I am getting 'Invalid State Error' on line 15 of rmc3.min.js.

Comment: You should try latest version e.g. [3.3.0](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/releases/tag/3.3.0) i.e. [`Signaling-Server.js`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/Signaling-Server.js)

Comment: Works, but crashes browser with no error messages about once in 10 minutes. Even from your link, as well as when using my server. Also some users don't see a screenshare - just a black screen. I am getting to feel that WebRTC is simply not ready for prime time yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Scalable-Screen-Broadcast demo:

- https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Scalable-Screen-Broadcast.html

And here it its source:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/demos/Scalable-Screen-Broadcast.html

The demo supports both Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, this one works! I will try to make it work on my machine now! Thanks whole lot!

Comment: For custom domains, it requires [this for chrome](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/desktopCapture) and [this for Firefox](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Firefox-Extensions/tree/master/enable-screen-capturing)

Comment: What is the purpose of parts which seem to record the stream there? Can they be safely removed?

Comment: Fixed here: [git/commit: Recording is disabled in the Scalable-Broadcast demos.](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/commit/0b808c383b8bb5ddcc0b26dea68b2c595c665e61)

Comment: One more question: if i manipulate connection.maxRelayLimitPerUser on individual peer's level (idea is to measure available bandwidth and reduce peering limit for those users with very poor bw, and increase for those with very good bw) - will this work correctly,without modifying server? Will it be able to handle the situation where different peers have all different limits of number of peers to connect? Of course that value is only determined once on startup and never changes then.

Comment: It is really very hard to determine exact available bandwidth; however we can add an option on "Scalable-Broadcast.js" that allows any peer to make himself "NEVER_RELAY" i.e. that peer will never be chosen for relay.

Comment: ok measuring bw is a separate problem, i agree it is hard. but manipulation of maxRelayLimitPerUser, on the level of individual peers, will work?

Comment: These links don't work anymore.